# Como saber si dos array tiene el mismo contenido? o si es diferente con respecto a un array?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (){
    
int arreglo[100],arreglo2[100];

int i,j,N;

scanf("%d",&N);

for(i=1;i<=N;i++){

scanf("%d",&arreglo[i]);

}

for(j=1;j<=N;j++){

scanf("%d",&arreglo2[j]);

}


if(i==j){

        
    printf("1");
    }
    else{
        
    printf("0");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: en caso de que el contenido sea el mismo, imprime 1, sino cero

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo ahí es comparar las variables i y j, por lo que siempre te dará true, lo que debes hacer es recorrer el arreglo e irlo comparando elemento por elemento para saber si su contenido es igual

Comment: siii, pero, es que el detalle es si le coloco un ciclo para recorrer los arreglos, al momento de impirir 1 o 0, entra en el bucle tambien. por otro lado, si las salidas las coloco fuera del bucle, se imprimen las dos :,v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te podría convenir en este caso trabajar con el [dato bool](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bool-in-c/) que puede guardar un `true` o un `false` (1 o 0).

Para evitar hacer otro ciclo, este dato booleano que comparará si los elementos de los arreglos coinciden lo puedes poner mientras rellenas el segundo arreglo.

Como quieres que imprima 0 o 1, puedes imprimir el dato booleano en formato de número

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/**
 * @param argc Number of arguments passed on command execution
 * @param argv Array of string arguments
 * @return program exit status
 */
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int n = 3;
    int arr[n], arr2[n];
    bool are_equal = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%s %d", "Ingrese el valor del arreglo 1 en la posición:", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", (arr + i));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%s %d", "Ingrese el valor del arreglo 2 en la posición:", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", (arr2 + i));
        if(arr2[i] != arr[i]){
            are_equal = false;
        }
    }

    printf("%hd", are_equal);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

De igual manera, te recomiendo que desde una vez, veas las funciones [`strto...`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol), que son una mejor manera de leer números que [`scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tener algo así:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (){
    
int arreglo[100],arreglo2[100];

int i,N;

bool igual = false;

scanf("%d",&N);

for(i=1;i<=N;i++){

 scanf("%d %d",&arreglo[i] &arreglo2[i]);
 if (arreglo[i] = arreglo2[i]
   igual = true;
 }
 else {
   printf("0");
   break;
 }
}




if(igual=true){

        
    printf("1");
    
    
}
```

Comment: `igual = true` es una operación de asignación, dado que igual es booleano puedes poner simplemente `if (igual)`, en otro caso no sugerido sería `igual == true` que esa comparación es totalmente inncesaria